# Enhancement authorities in spring Oauth2

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am working on project where i have an person having multiple role in different tenant. so I want to customize authority to get role and ownership of that role ex.

```
"authorities": [ 
     {    
          "authority": "ROLE_store", 
          "ownership": "sec 18" 
     } 
 ]
```

### Spring code:

```
private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthoritiesForStore(){
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_"+"store"));
            System.out.print("authorities :"+authorities);
        return authorities;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this solution solved my issue and it has almost same result as i wanted.

```
public class CustomTokenEnhancer implements TokenEnhancer {

        @Autowired
        EmployeeService employeeService;

        @Override
        public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {

            User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
            String username = user.getUsername();

            List<Map<String, Object>> credential = employeeService.fetchEmployeesRoleCredentials(username);

                final Map<String, Object> additionalInfo = new HashMap<>();

                additionalInfo.put("credentials", credential);
                // additionalInfo.put("authorities", user.getAuthorities());

                ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken).setAdditionalInformation(additionalInfo);

            return accessToken;

        }

    }
```